# All links in my code work except these ones

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

This is my html code sofar

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="Images/samsung-logo.png" alt="Samsung Logo" width="150"></a>
        <ul class="menubalk">
            <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
            <a href="#assortiment-scroll"><li>Assortiment</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="bg">
        <video src="videos/S22-Ultra-unboxing.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
        <div class="bg-text">Nieuwe S22 Ultra</div>
        <a href=""><div class="bg-text-url">Discover</div></a>
</div>
```

The last link with `class="bg-text-url"` work but the first 3 don't.
Am I not seeing something or ...

EDIT: when I first started the project it did work. And I haven't changed anything to the `header` since.

To make it easier: https://jsfiddle.net/x7ewtvqu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your anchor tags are not working is a combination of using `display: inline;` styles and `position: absolute;`. To fix this issue, update your styles to be accurate to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/x7jnLpue/3/) JSFiddle. I have also corrected some of your syntax.

Comment: I also have this code: `<a href=""><div class="bg-text-url">Discover</div></a>` and you  can click on it. So I don't know why there should be an `href` attribute.

Comment: The ``href`` attribute is the page that the anchor tag redirects to, if you are just looking for some dummy anchor tags then use a ``#`` for the anchor attribute. But you can read up on this more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: I changed some things. Can you have another look?

Comment: Could you please further explain what you mean by: "the links aren't working"?

Comment: I just don't get like the hand icon when I hover over them with my mouse.

Comment: Please check my post for recently added edits.

Comment: I have put the EDIT code in my css tab. And I still don't get the hand icon.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me, make sure that you have imported your CSS and are correctly applying the style. Check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7kb3z68w/1/

Comment: I have put the whole project in the post

Comment: Please check the second edit for further information based on the rest of your code.

Comment: And it still doesn't work. but maybe if you use the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7ewtvqu/ it will be easier.

Comment: Please check this JSFiddle, it seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/x7jnLpue/3/. I am aware that some of the styles are incorrect however, you should be able to easily customize it without breaking the anchor tags now.

Comment: it did work but now `contact` and `assortiment` are under the picture `<img src="Images/samsung-logo.png" alt="Samsung Logo" width="150">` while they are suppose to be next to it

Comment: Make sure that you also copied over the flex styles I have used.

Comment: That worked. But now I can scroll in the width.

Comment: Just add an ``overflow-x: hidden`` to whatever is scrolling, or make sure all your widths do not conflict with the screen size. I didn't get that issue when I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="Images/samsung-logo.png" alt="Samsung Logo" width="150"></a>
        <ul class="menubalk">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Assortiment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="bg">
   <video src="videos/S22-Ultra-unboxing.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
   <div class="bg-text">Nieuwe S22 Ultra</div>            
   <div class="bg-text-url"><a href="#">Discover</a></div>
</div>
```

Element `a` not allowed as child of element `ul` in this context.
Also when you using a `div` element `a` not allowed as a parent child.

Answer (score 0):

1. using `div` in `a` tag is  semantically incorrect. You should use `span` tag.
2. don't use `li` in `a` tag. Use `a` in `li` tag.
3. if you want to use `div` in `a` tag just use:

   ```
   <div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='http://google.com';">
   Hello world
   </div>
   ```

or use:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <span style="display: block;">
        Hello world
    </span>
</a>
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/abstract-business-arrow-up-logo-icon-vector-design-template-vector-id1140553971?k=20&m=1140553971&s=612x612&w=0&h=7-a1JjWAf8c5qKF46FRgdFg-3jva9qo80hqh0z_Y34A=" alt="Samsung Logo" width="150"></a>
        <ul class="menubalk">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#assortiment-scroll">Assortiment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="bg">
        <video src="videos/S22-Ultra-unboxing.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
        <div class="bg-text">Nieuwe S22 Ultra</div>
        <a href="#"><span class="bg-text-url">Discover</span></a>
</div>
```